# Pages not indexing on Google Search Console

Tags: wordpress, indexing, blogs

I have a ton of my news posts not indexed cause of several errors.

See in the image below, emails is being added to the link of a post, or /feed. How do i stop google from seeing my post links like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eEEZ.png)

No youtube video has really helped cause their reasons isn't similar to mine

Answer (score 0):

Please redirect 404 page to homepage.

Comment: its a lot will i start redirecting all of them manually?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).